# 2D videogame using DirectX and C#. Which options do I have?

Tags: c#, .net, uwp, directx

I'm a beginner and I would like to start with drawing some images and making them move in a game loop, but most of the docs I've found are for C++ and seem outdated.

In 2019, is there a good mix to create simple 2D videogames?

NOTICE: I'm a UWP developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is very general but i would suggest that you start with the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/gaming/e2e

On the very same page you can find additional resources with examples: https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples

Google is your friend!

Comment: I explicitly mention C# because all the docs are focused on C++

Comment: Perhaps MonoGame http://www.monogame.net/ is what you're looking for in that case.
Same goes here, check the MS documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/graphics-games/monogame/platforms/uwp